# VHDL error in Vivado states "target has 17 bits, source has 33 bits"

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am receiving an error that says my target is 17 bits but the source is 33 bits. I don't understand how this is the case when the two things being added together are each 16 bits. This should result in a 17-bit sum. I am unsure as to how it comes to 33 bits.

I have tried converting each addend into an sfixed value because that is what the target is. I have tried without this conversion. I have tried using the resize function on each addend in order to guarantee each is 16 bits. This method worked but created an incorrect circuit.

`N` and `I` are both generic integers of value 4.

This is the problem statement:

```
wx12 <= wx(1*(4*N)-1 downto 0*(4*N)) + wx(2*(4*N)-1 downto 1*(4*N));
```

This is wx and how it is defined/populated:

```
signal wx : sfixed (4*N*I-1 downto 0);

wx(1*(4*N)-1 downto 0*(4*N)) <= x(1*(2*N)-1 downto 0*(2*N)) * w(1*(2*N)-1 downto 0*(2*N));                                                                       
wx(2*(4*N)-1 downto 1*(4*N)) <= x(2*(2*N)-1 downto 1*(2*N)) * w(2*(2*N)-1 downto 1*(2*N));                                                                       
wx(3*(4*N)-1 downto 2*(4*N)) <= x(3*(2*N)-1 downto 2*(2*N)) * w(3*(2*N)-1 downto 2*(2*N));                                                                       
wx(4*(4*N)-1 downto 3*(4*N)) <= x(4*(2*N)-1 downto 3*(2*N)) * w(4*(2*N)-1 downto 3*(2*N));
```

This is w and how it is defined:

```
 constant w : sfixed ((2*N*I)-1 downto 0) := to_sfixed(1, N-1, -N) 
                                             & to_sfixed(1, N-1, -N)
                                             & to_sfixed(1, N-1, -N)
                                             & to_sfixed(1, N-1, -N);
```

This is x and how it is defined:

```
x : in sfixed ((2*N*I)-1 downto 0);
```

I expected a result of 17 bits but the error below shows the result is actually 33 bits.

> [Synth 8-690] width mismatch in assignment; target has 17 bits, source has 33 bits ["C:/Users/devon/project_1/project_1.srcs/sources_1/new/neural_network.vhd":104]

Comment: You don't provide a  [mcve], please do so. However addition ("+") of two values of type sfixed can be found in the IEEE package body generic_fixed_pkg which is instantiated as fixed_pkg and demonstrates both operands are resized according to maximum of operand left bounds and the minimum operand right bounds, in this case producing a 33 bit result while also apparently not retaining the sign of the left operand.  You'd be better served simulating your design prior to synthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If N and I are 4, then you have this:
`wx12 <= wx(15 downto 0) + wx(31 downto 16);`

The fixed_point libraries, by default, behave differently to numeric_std.

1. Both operands are re-shaped to be (max(a,b) downto (min(a,b))
2. The result has bit growth.

Because max(a,b) = 31, and min(a,b) = 0, both operands are bit extended to (31 downto 0) - 32 bit. It then has a single bit of growth, giving the result.

This is all because the fixed point libraries respects the index as the 2^n. to do what you want, you need to re-align the 2nd operand to (15 downto 0) yourself.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is the sum of each 16-bit group in wx. Is there a way to achieve this using dynamic allocation through a for-generate statement? I am able to sum wx right now but only because I hard-coded four signals to contain each 16-bit chunk. Then two more signals to find the sum of the first two. Then one more signal to find that sum. As you can see, this method only works for four inputs (I), or four 16-bit chunks. I would like to be able to set I equal to however many inputs and not have to create seperate signals for each case. Any tips or ideas?